# NotificationCenter post to update UI element on main thread?

Tags: swift3, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotificationcenter

I have this code in my project:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
          self,
          selector: #selector(self.didUpdateHistory),
          name: NSNotification.Name.init("didUpdateHistory"),
          object: nil)
}

func didUpdateHistory() {
   // Update some UI elements
}
```

Now my question is: if I post the notification from some class in my project **and that trigger wasn't caused by a UI element,** do I still need to wrap the code in the didUpdateHistory func with `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` or should I wrap the post call itself?

Also, does it matter where you add the observer and from where you post the notification?

Answer (score 7):

You have to wrap the post call only.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "didUpdateHistory", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```

Read more about Delivering Notifications To Particular Threads
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Threading.html